# How to get the inserted id from table a and use the id to insert into table b

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I would like to save a record in table a and get the inserted id; and get this id to save into another record in table b.

In Service:

```
public Long save(Entity entity, String a) {
    entity = entityRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
    Long insertedEntityId = entity.getId();
    EntityB entityb = new EntityB(
        insertedEntityId,
        a);
    entityb = entityBRepository.saveAndFlush(entityb);
    return entityb.getId();
}
```

In EntityB:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

However, I got the error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table '...'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

How to fix this problem?

I'm using SQL server 2012, Spring boot 2.3, Java 11.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use JPA? If so, you generally shouldn't be using `insertedEntityId` directly but instead using a `OneToOne` or similar mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create constructor receive two parameters as you do in the lines:

```
EntityB entityb = new EntityB(insertedEntityId, a);
```

In that constructor, assume something like this:

```
public EntityB(Long id, String param) {
        this.id = id;
        this.param = param;
    }
```

The lines

```
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

are not correct, it is just the getter method using for retrieving id. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

When using `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, the column must be an `identity` column in SQL Server (i.e. auto-increment). When `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is used, the identity is managed by the database server and thus your app does not send any value for the `id` column. If the column is not defined as `identity` in SQL Server but defined as `NOT NULL`, then you will get the error you see.

Also, unlikely needed, but add this line `private long id;` before `public Long getId()` to explicitly make sure the decoration applies to `id`.